# if statements to check if Swing components are empty or not

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, if-statement

I am current writing if statements to check if the swing components (JtextField & JcomboBox (x2)) within my GUI are empty or not. I initially just made an if statement for the scenario that the JTextField and two JComboBox's are empty, therefore dispay error dialog:

```
  if (NameOfCruise.equals("") && startLValue.equals("") && endLValue.equals("")) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame2,
         "Please Complete Form.", "Error",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
               System.out.print("Please Complete Form.");
               Frame2.setVisible(true);
                    }
```

However, upon further thinking, I have realized that there are more scenario's I have not considered. I realized I need error messages for the following scenario's: 
1. Cruise Name, startL or endL values are all left empty.
2. If Cruise Name left empty but StartL and EndL are both selected.
3. If Cruise Name & StartL left empty but EndL selected.
4. If Cruise Name & EndL left empty but StartL selected.

& probably more which I haven't realized yet. I started to implement if statements for the above but have came across a problem.

Here is my code so far:

```
 // 2. Error message CruiseName left empty but StartL and EndL are both selected.
  if(NameOfCruise.equals("") && !startLValue.equals("") || !endLValue.equals("")){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame2,
          "Please enter Cruise Name.", "Error",
             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             System.out.print("Name of Cruise not entered. Please enter Cruise Name.\n");
             Frame2.setVisible(true);
                        } 

 //  3. Error message if Name of Cruise & StartL left empty but EndL is selected.
  if(startLValue.equals("") && NameOfCruise.equals("") || !endLValue.equals("")){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame2,
         "Please Select a Start Location.", "Error",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         System.out.print("Select a start location.\n");
         Frame2.setVisible(true);
              }
```

**The Problem:**

If you look at the code above, the way I tested (3) is by leaving the Cruise name and StartL location empty and by entering the EndL value. However I am coming up with the error dialog from task (2) - which is reasonable as the cruise name is empty.

**Question(s):** 
1. How do I code the if statement so that the appropriate error messages display for each scenario? At the moment, I am getting two error dialog boxes with each message.
2. Is there a better, much more effecient way to code these scenario's rather than having if statements for each case.
3. Can you suggest any scenario's I am missing?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is, instead of making a trillion different `if` statements, just make 3. One for `StartL` one for `EndL` and one for `NameOfCruise`. It's more compact, it's simpler, and you dont have to make an `if` statement for each different combination scenario.

Comment: Thank you, don't know why I didn't think of that, but nevertheless, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A very abstract answer, You have three inputs, two states (empty or not) per input, results in eight different scenarios, ońly some of them are OK.

Map the three booleans to integers 0..7. Create a Sting[] table with 8 entries, null for no error and a non-null entry with the appropriate error message, and select according to the result from the mapping.

Tables are frequently a good way to simplify app logic.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience I would try to check each condition separately, one after another. If the condition holds: fine. If not I would store the recommended action ("Please enter cruise name", "Please select start location", etc etc), i.e. in a list of strings.

After all conditions have been checked and the list of strings is not empty, you can display the JOptionPane and fill it with information from the list. So each condition not met should be printed inside the pane.